# Convergence of the sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$ where $x_n = \frac{1}{1.3}+\frac{1}{2.5}+...\frac{1}{n(2n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

> Let $\left\{x_n\right\}$ be a sequence where $x_n = \frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{2\cdot5}+...\frac{1}{n\cdot(2n+1)}$

I have to calculate, to which point does the sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$ converge, using Euler's constant($\gamma$). That is, I have to use the fact that the sequence $\left\{\gamma_n\right\}$ converges to $\gamma$, where $\gamma_n =1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\log n$.

But I cannot reduce $x_n$ to any form relating $\gamma_n$. Please help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1590619/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. This help proves to be enough for me.

Comment: @MartinR neither of these questions provide the answer requested by the OP.

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes, but I got a hint how to proceed. Your detailed answer is of great help. Thanks to both of you.: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k(2k+1)}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}-2\left(\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}-2\sum_{k=2}^{2n+1}\frac1k+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}-2\left(-1+\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac1k\right)\\
&=2+2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac1k\\
&=2+2(\gamma_n+\ln{(n)})-2(\gamma_{2n+1}+\ln{(2n+1)})\\
&=2+2\left(\gamma_n-\gamma_{2n+1}+\ln{\left(\frac{n}{2n+1}\right)}\right)\\
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\therefore\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k(2k+1)}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2+2\left(\gamma_n-\gamma_{2n+1}+\ln{\left(\frac{n}{2n+1}\right)}\right)\right)\\
&=2+2\ln{\left(\frac12\right)}\\
&=\boxed{2(1-\ln{(2)})}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok, Thank you Sir.